# How to get max of "not exists" query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm not super great with SQL, but I'm using it for a project. Below is the query I would like to write, but of course it isn't valid SQL

```
select * from a
where not exists (
  select * from b
  where a.name = b.name) common
where a.id > max(common.id)
```

My goal is to get the rows in `a` that do not join with those in `b`, but only those with a greater `id` than any of the ones that do join. The point of this is so that I can begin filling a database with values, stop, and then continue later where I left off.

I'm using sqlite with python; I know I could do two queries with python, but I'm guessing there is a way to do it with SQL (and I'm assuming that's 'better')

Dump:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "a" (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Name`  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)
);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(16,'Bob');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(17,'George');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(18,'Jimmy');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(19,'Billy');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(20,'Johnny');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(21,'James');
INSERT INTO a VALUES(22,'Bart');

CREATE TABLE "b" (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)
);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(16,'Bob');
INSERT INTO b VALUES(19,'Billy');
COMMIT;
```

There are other columns, so these aren't identical tables, but the query should get Johnny, James, and Bart from table `a`.

Comment: Please provide as [mcve] a `.dump` of a suitably tailored toy database in SQLite.

Comment: @Yunnosch edited

Comment: @CL. The last sentence should be clear enough, should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose:

- make a convenient common table expression for the inner join (first line)
- select all from a which are not in ab (second line and fourth line)
- restrict according to desired condition (third line)

Note that the ids from `ab` are identical to those from `a` which join with `b`. So their max is the max from ids in a which join.

I simply output `*`, using only the desired fields is possible should be easy.

Code:

```
with ab(id, field) as (select id, a.name from a join b using(id))
select * from a
where id > (select max(id) from ab)
except select * from ab;
```

Output:

```
20|Johnny
21|James
22|Bart
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gets all rows from `a` that are bigger than the largest corresponding value in row `b`:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.id > (select max(b.id) from b where a.a_field = b.b_field)
```

It assumes that at least one record matches in `b`.

If you want to include all values, even when none exist, then I think this will do:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.id > all (select b.id from b where a.a_field = b.b_field)
```

Comment: Interesting; that's close, but I don't think that's quite what I want. My question is a little vague, but I'm want to compare `a.id` with `a.id` again, rather than `b.id`. I think I see a way to do this with a join somehow, but I'm not sure.